# Any idea when the data from the German consulate in Chennai will be removed, if we wanted to book a slot for the second time?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany

How much time does the German consulate in Chennai take to remove the details from their database of people who already attended the visa interview?

I have attended a job-seeker visa interview on January 26, 2018 at the consulate, and got a rejection letter on February 6, 2018.

I am trying to book a slot for the second time and get an error saying that the email address already exists.

Can some please let me know how many days it takes to remove my data?

Comment: Did/do you apply for an interview creating an account?

Comment: What did the rejection letter state about reapplication? They most likely will never remove data that you've had a visa application and that it was rejected. It's also quite possible that you will not be offered a second interview so soon (the rejection letter would likely include specifics), they have already made the decision and it won't change if there aren't any major changes in your circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any option on the website to use your email as a login? Or a password reset option? Because it sounds like you are trying to create a new account when it would be better to re-use your existing details.

If nothing else works, create a new free email account and use that.